# How to make the net run on the GPU

Tags: android, tensorflow

I started integrating my company's implementation of CNN into our Android App.

As a reference I used [TensorFlow sample for mobile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android).

Unfortunately, I'm experiencing long execution times(around 10-15 sec). On our servers, it takes only 1 sec.

I tried figuring out whether this execution is taking place on the CPU or the GPU using the Android Profiler in Android Studio and notices that it runs on the CPU.

I'd like to share this problem with the community in order to check if someone encountered the same problem as I did.

I'm using Samsung Galaxi A5 and Google Pixel.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using just the CPU.  There are two possible explanations:

- The recommended TensorFlow build mechanism creates static libraries that don't have GPU support enabled; see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile
- I have not yet managed to track down TensorFlow support for anything other than NVidia GPUs.  Your Galaxy A5 and Google Pixel don't have an NVidia GPUs.

Comment: Can you please share with me a link to supported GPUs? I could find one. About the link you share, also it informs that when you use the Makefile to build the static libs it doesn't support GPU I'm pretty sure that it's the same for Android's Gradle build system. The Gradle also builds .so that are probably doesn't support GPU. I wonder if the solution is to build my own .so libraries that speaks with the TensorFlow service and try to enable the GPU capability myself.

Comment: Update: I found the below link that specifies the TensorFlow for iOS limitations. One of them is that the GPU is unsupported. I'm sure that is covers the Android also because the TensorFlow Mobile core is cross-platform. http://machinethink.net/blog/tensorflow-on-ios/

Comment: "Can you please share with me a link to supported GPUs?"  I don't have one.  But I can see pages that talk about TensorFlow with NVidia GPUs.